# Can't send WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to some controls

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm working on (yet another) [keyboard layout switcher](https://github.com/kurumpa/dotSwitcher) and got strange troubles with Skype window (ver 6.22 on win7 x64). [Any combinations](https://github.com/kurumpa/dotSwitcher/blob/master/LowLevelAdapter.cs#L33) of GetForegroundWindow() / GetFocus() / GetParentWindow() don't succeed to change the layout **only inside the message input** and, even more strange, **only if more than one character is entered**. Other cases work perfectly nice except wpf apps which refuse to obey without focusedHandle stuff.

```
public static void SetNextKeyboardLayout()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint processId;
        uint activeThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
        uint currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

        AttachThreadInput(activeThreadId, currentThreadId, true);
        IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus();
        AttachThreadInput(activeThreadId, currentThreadId, false);

        PostMessage(focusedHandle == IntPtr.Zero ? hWnd : focusedHandle, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, INPUTLANGCHANGE_FORWARD, HKL_NEXT);
    }
```

I'm new to winapi things, so any help will be kindly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please, post your code.

Answer (score 2):

After disassembling some of working products i've figured out that i was close to the right algorythm which looks like this:

```
public static void SetNextKeyboardLayout()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    var threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
    var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

    var info = new GUITHREADINFO();
    info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
    var success = GetGUIThreadInfo(threadId, ref info);

    // target = hwndCaret || hwndFocus || (AttachThreadInput + GetFocus) || hwndActive || GetForegroundWindow
    AttachThreadInput(threadId, currentThreadId, true);
    IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus();
    AttachThreadInput(threadId, currentThreadId, false);
    if (success)
    {
        if (info.hwndCaret != IntPtr.Zero) { hWnd = info.hwndCaret; }
        else if (info.hwndFocus != IntPtr.Zero) { hWnd = info.hwndFocus; }
        else if (focusedHandle != IntPtr.Zero) { hWnd = focusedHandle; }
        else if (info.hwndActive != IntPtr.Zero) { hWnd = info.hwndActive; }
    }
    else
    {
        hWnd = focusedHandle;
    }
    if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) { hWnd = GetForegroundWindow(); }

    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, INPUTLANGCHANGE_FORWARD, HKL_NEXT);
}
```

But the problem was not in finding PostMessage target hWnd, but in skype's input handling. I have solved it by adding a tiny delay before `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` so skype can properly process all the input sent to it. Now i have to get things working without this delay but this is another story.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: `PostMessage(hWnd,WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST,0,(LPARAM)HKL_NEXT);`

**P.S.**:
Under Windows 10 any WM_`INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` crashes Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Best way with Windows 10 -- is emulate keys for switch keyboard layout, like this:

```
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
Sleep(10);
keybd_event(VK_SPACE,0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```