# How to send WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to app with modal window?

Tags: c#, winapi, modal-dialog, postmessage

I wrote a keyboard switcher, which works well, but fails if current application has modal window opened. On keyboard switch I do the following

```
hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, handle);
```

where

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessage")]
private static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

but the language does not change.

How would I accomplish this?

---

Adding get root owner improved situation, but didn't help completely.

Adding call for `GetDesktopWindow` didn't help:

```
hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
InputLangChangeRequest(hwnd, language);
hwnd = GetRootOwner();
InputLangChangeRequest(hwnd, language);
```

---

Code is here https://github.com/dims12/NormalKeyboardSwitcher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't send WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST to some controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720728/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GetAncestor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633502(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Retrieves the owned root window by walking the chain of parent and
>   owner windows returned by GetParent.

This should return the main UI window if there is a modal window, or a chain of modal window.

```
hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
hwnd = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER); //#define GA_ROOTOWNER 3
```

---

Apparently `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` fails if the target itself is a dialog based application (I don't know why!) To solve the problem you can post `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message to dialog's descendants (in addition to `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message to the dialog itself)

```
static bool MyEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
    return true;
}

static void Foo()
{
    //Greek input for testing:
    var hkl = LoadKeyboardLayout("00000408", KLF_ACTIVATE);
    var hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (hwnd != null)
    {
        hwnd = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)hkl);

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(100);
        GetClassName(hwnd, buf, 100);

        //if this is a dialog class then post message to all descendants 
        if (buf.ToString() == "#32770")
            EnumChildWindows(hwnd, MyEnumProc, (IntPtr)hkl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help. May be the task is opposite? Need to find deepest descendant window, not ancestor?

Comment: I have checked window handle with WinSpy++ and found that: (1) the sequence above finds window incorrectly and (2) if I rely on other process (tracking of foreground window change) and get the same hex of a handle, sending message still doesn't switch the language

Comment: I was partially wrong: the handle is correct both ways (incorrect hadnler was due to switch to debugger), but the language is still not changed.

Comment: I thought you said it works when window does not have a modal dialog on top. So it should work if `GetAncestor` returns the right window handle. I tested this with Notepad. It also works when Notepad's About Dialog is active. Using `LoadKeyboardLayout("00000408", KLF_ACTIVATE)` for test. Note that this only changes the keyboard language.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have checked and it works with modal window (File->Open) in `Notepad`. But it doesn't work if application has only one window and it's modal (`Pageant`)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work for dialog based applications. See the changes for getting passed that.