# How does Windows changes keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard-layout

The hotkeys for doing so are:

`Alt+Shift` - Windows 7 and `Win button + Space` in Win 8 and 10.

Programmatically I can do that using `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`, but it is not the way *Windows* does that. I am trying to figure out how Windows changes the layout. Using *spy++* I figured out that Windows sends `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message which is changing layout, so I tried it myself:

```
SendMessage(myHWND, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, 0xCC, 0x4190419);
```

I have keyboard hook bind, when press f1 do the sendmessage to currently active window's active control.

but it didn't work, though the messages in spy++ are thes same:

[image: img]

first one using "Windows hotkey"/"Taskbar" to change layout, it works. Second my message, it did not work. Am I missing something, why message works for "Windows" but not for me.

The `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` works, but it freezes some certain apps, and I would like to figure out the way Windows does the layout changing to avoid that.

-- **update**.

In DxO Photolab 3 it freezes when using WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE in "Export to Disk" Dialog:

When you change layout using "Windows" Method(Keyboard Hotkey/Taskbar):
[image: 2020 04 19 - 22'11'40_rect]
Works normally, no freezing.

Posting the WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
[image: 2020 04 19 - 22'10'06_rect]
Received the WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST and froze:
[image: 2020 04 19 - 22'05'07_rect]

Also similar freezing I've seen in Skype, MS Office, Adobe After Effects.

Comment: "`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` works, but it freezes some certain apps"  What function are you using to deliver this message?

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried both `SendMessage` and `PostMessage`, neither of them works for "certain apps".

Comment: You can use `SendInput` to simulate `Win button + Space` in Win 8 and 10.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I know, but what if user was holding Win button when I did that?

Comment: @BladeMight Use `GetAsyncKeyState` to detect if  Win button be pressed.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: hi , has the question been solved?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Well, I still don't know how Windows changes layout, I can only "emulate" the windows keyboard layout changing by windows hotkey, so I guess that is not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

From [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-inputlangchangerequest#remarks),

> When the `DefWindowProc` function receives the
>   `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message, **it activates the new input locale**
>   and notifies the application of the change by sending the
>   `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message.

We can view the details through spy++.

[image: 1]

Only after the application receives the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message, it will activate the new input locale, and notifies the application of the change by sending the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message.

A simple test:

[image: 2]

According to my understanding, what actually works is the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message, but I have not found an alternative API to complete its work.

For the freezing problem of some certain apps you encountered, I found some similar cases.

Refer [@Barmak Shemirani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118612/11128312),

> Apparently `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` fails if the target itself is a
>   dialog based application (I don't know why!) To solve the problem you
>   can post `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message to dialog's descendants (in
>   addition to `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` message to the dialog itself)

Updated:

My test code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{       
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x00070EBA; // hwnd of skype
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image: 2]

Comment: I have tried the workarounds from answer you referenced, no luck, my case is different, it just freezes no mather what I do. Bun anyway thank you for your time. "**it activates the new input locale**": I would like to know what happened at this point... But "Windows"(when you use the keyboard shortcut/taskbar to change layout) manages to do that without `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`, how is that. I suspect that Windows "has" somewhere that layout instance and can change it by itself without notifying the app with the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`, only with the `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`...

Comment: @BladeMight Which applications will be frozen? Do you mind adding these details to the question? Include code that can reproduce the problem and the application you tried.

Comment: @BladeMight  I have tested in Skype, MS Office, but I cannot reproduce your problem. Did you send `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` to test? To make the test results convincing, I added gif image.

Comment: I think the Skype/MS Office problem was with older versions(a year or so ago), and it was inside "text input" - not in window itself, currently I too cannot reproduce that with them, but with DxO Photolab 3 freezing is happening.

Comment: @BladeMight All right. This may be the problem of message handling inside DxO Photolab 3. Because this is third-party app, I cannot try it. If you want to dig more information about this app, I suggest you can post a new thread about this app.

Comment: @BladeMight Finally, I think it is necessary to end this thread. As can be seen from the official documentation, the keyboard layout will only change after the app receives `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`, and then the app will issue `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` to notify us that the layout has been changed. And I don't think Microsoft wants us to pursue the processing behind the message, we just need to know how to use it. In addition, if you think that understanding this is very important for your project, I suggest that you can send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app.

Comment: Well "message handling inside DxO" might be the case, I guess.Thank you for your time.