# Switch keyboard layout Works but NOT Always

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a bit new to Autohotkey.

I have 3 Language installed, one of them I use very rarely. so I want to Toggle switch only between 2 languages (EN-RU) using WIN+Space.
I searched web found code which was short and logically close to my need, I done some modification to be more object like and personalised conditions.
Code: Select all - Expand View

```
#Space::
  SetFormat, Integer, H
  Lang := { "EN" : "0x4090409" , "RU" : "0x4190419", "HE": "0x40D040D" }

  WinGet, WinID,, A
  ThreadID:=DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Int", WinID, "Int", "0")
  InputLocaleID:=DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "Int", ThreadID)

  if(InputLocaleID=Lang.RU OR InputLocaleID=Lang.HE)
    SendMessage, 0x50,, % Lang.EN,, A
  else if(InputLocaleID=Lang.EN)
    SendMessage, 0x50,, % Lang.RU,, A
Exit
```

it works well with most of programs but with few of them it only get switch to RU.

Works Well: Chrome, notePad, notePad++, Notion, VScode, Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA,
Doesn't Work: OneNote Windows 10 app (even so in Onenote 2016 it works fine)

If someone can help me with it I would Greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You may not need to create a hotkey for this at all. In the following link, the functionality of Windows to toggle between, or switch directly to a, specific language(s) is discussed. In fact, it even shows it for EN and RU. https://winaero.com/blog/change-hotkeys-switch-keyboard-layout-windows-10/

Comment: (Just speculating) Additionally, since the hotkey `#Space` is the same as the built-in Windows hotkey for this, that *may* be the source of the issues.

Comment: Thanks for Reply!
the problem with this example is that it will toggle between all my 3 Languages I have (EN - HE - RU).
defining key switch for each is uncomfortable. 
so this is the reason I try to make a code to toggle between 2 languages.

for the most part the code is working well unfortunately beside Onenote.
I tried another key combination, the problem is the same.

Comment: Understood. I am also experiencing this issue with Edge when attempting to replicate your problem. I suspect this may apply to all UWP applications. Here are some links for further research: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720728/cant-send-wm-inputlangchangerequest-to-some-controls https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28258 https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=63062

Comment: Thank you very much for your will to help)

Answer (score 1):

related answer [Autohotkey Forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=69414&p=299021#p299021)

```
  #Space:: ;  Switch keyboard (EN-RU)

    Lang := { "EN": 0x4090409, "RU": 0x4190419 }
    ; For compatibility with UWP apps, get the thread of the focused
    ; control, not the active window.  This is necessary because those
    ; apps are hosted within a window owned by a different process.
    ControlGetFocus Focused, A
    ControlGet CtrlID, Hwnd,, % Focused, A
    ; Using Ptr vs. Int vs. UInt won't matter in these cases
    ThreadID := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", CtrlID, "Ptr", 0)
    ; HKL is a handle type (64-bit on x64)
    InputLocaleID := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "Ptr")

    if (InputLocaleID != Lang.EN)
      SendMessage, 0x50,, % Lang.EN,, ahk_id %CtrlID%
    else
      SendMessage, 0x50,, % Lang.RU,, ahk_id %CtrlID%
    Exit
```

Comment: For me, this still doesn't work in Edge nor when the taskbar is active. Does is work for you in the OneNote UWP app? Interestingly, though, it *does* work when the desktop is active. Since this is always available, the solution may lie in sending it to that.

Comment: yes it work at least for now) in every app I tried including Onenote and Edge and this is why I shared it here)

Comment: there is another code variation in the link I posted you can try it.